# Are there any drawbacks to using TAP (Temporary Access Password)?

Tags: azure, passwordless

In 2021 Microsoft introduced TAP (Temporary Access Password) and it became popular especially for onboarding users. Are there any drawbacks generally to consider when implementing this option for user sign-in?

One of the drawbacks is when an unauthorized admin creates a TAP for another user and can log in without any notification sent to the user (This is how Microsoft Azure Works now).